# Wordpress: import scss from plugin in my theme

Tags: wordpress, sass, build

I'm working on a theme and plugin that share components. In my theme I have a scss file and in this I want to import a main.scss file from my plugin. This is the situation:

Plugin main.scss

```
@import "slick";
@import "slick_theme";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~aos/dist/aos.css";
@import "../../../my-directory/**/*.scss";
```

Theme main.scss

```
@import "../../plugins/my-plugin/assets/src/scss/main";
```

II can't compile the main.scss of my theme because it can't resolve the url of node_modules and the directory with wildcards.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**(A) Easiest (and fastest!) way: Use full relative path!**

As SASS don't support the wild cards in SASS files using `@`-rules: just remove wild cards and write full relative path to node-modules like `@import '../../complete/relative/path/to/node/module/dir/file.scss'` ;-)

**(B) ALTERNATIVE: Set `includePath`**

Set node directory as `includePath` for your project. As I don't know the compiler you use here are the information how to do in original SASS (but 'includePath' variable is almost the same):

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api#includepaths

In that case you are able to `@import` only by using the filename.

---

**Additional notes:**

- In SASS rule `@import` does NOT support mulitple includes at all. Means: in a SASS file `@import '*.scss'` (as you try in your example by using wildcard `*` in filename) will not work at all. You ALLWAYS need  to specify a concrete single file: `@import 'concreteFile.scss'`.
- In SASS you can remove the suffix `.scss` from filenames. As this `@import` path/to/filename'` works as well.